# Working on a Caeser Cipher, however the text is not being returned as it should be?

Tags: python

Whenever I type to encode "hello world" by a shift of 1, I get "ifmmp xpsme1" which is correct. However whenever I try to decode it, it gives me "hello9worldJ" which obviously isn't correct.

```
def encryption(string, shift):
    cipher = ''
    for char in string:
        if char == ' ':
            cipher = cipher + char
        elif char.isupper():
            cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
    shift = str(shift)

    return cipher + shift


def cipherDecrypt(word, key):
    decryptString = ""
    for i in word:
        charvalue = ord(i) - key
        if charvalue < 97:
            charvalue = ord("z") - (96-charvalue)
            decryptString += chr(charvalue)
        elif charvalue == 32:
            decryptString += " "
        else:
            decryptString += chr(charvalue)
    return decryptString

def main():
    decision = ""
    while decision != "stop":
        decision = input("Would you like to 'encode' or 'decode' or 'stop': ")
        if decision == "encode":
            text = input("Enter a string to encode: ")
            num = int(input("Enter your number to shift: "))
            print("Original input: ", text)
            print("After encryption: ", encryption(text, num))
        elif decision == "decode":
            text = input("Enter a string to decode: ")
            num = int(input("Enter your number to shift: "))
            print("Original input: ", text)
            print("After encryption: ", cipherDecrypt(text, num))


main()
```

Comment: `elif charvalue == 32` will never be executed since that case also matches `if charvalue < 97`.

Comment: Your decryption routine should do the same tests in the same order as the encryption routine, just subtract the shift instead of add.  In fact, write one function...use a shift (positive or negative) to encode and the opposite sign to decode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because when you come to the " " `(ord(" ") == 32)`, the if condition is getting satisfied and thus you end up with a 9 instead of the space.

A very simple fix: 
change the if to :
`if charvalue < 97 and charvalue != ord(" ") - key:`

and the elif to :
`elif charvalue == ord(" ") - key`

The reason for the `- key` part is that you are setting charvalue to `ord(i) - key` in the loop. You need to check each case after subtracting the key, meaning that in your case, you should check for space if `charvalue == 31` (32 - 1)

Answer (score 0):

At the point you do

```
        elif charvalue == 32:
            decryptString += " "
```

you have already set charvalue as

```
        charvalue = ord(i) - key
```

but see your original encoded string: spaces become spaces when encoded, but at this point you've "decoded" a space before checking what it is.

You have to do this:

```
def cipherDecrypt(word, key):
    decryptString = ""
    for i in word:
        charvalue = ord(i) - key
        if i == 32:  # Check if the character is a space BEFORE decoding it
            decryptString += " "
        elif charvalue < 97:
            charvalue = ord("z") - (96-charvalue)
            decryptString += chr(charvalue)
        else:
            decryptString += chr(charvalue)
    return decryptString
```

---

However some subtle bugs remain; a better check is to verify each character if it can be decoded before progressing:

```
def cipherEncrypt(word, key):
    cipher = ''
    for char in string:
        if char.isupper():
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65)
        elif char.islower():
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            cipher += char
    return cipher
```

This way, you'll cipher letters and pass anything else through.

Plus, given the nature of the Caesar cipher, the definition of `cipherDecrypt` is trivial:

```
def cipherDecrypt(word, key):
    return cipherEncrypt(word, -key)
```